# When does it matter that `this` is an rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, this, language-lawyer

I know that the [type of `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067244/type-of-this-pointer) is a [prvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) ("pure" rvalue) pointer, and that it may be made a pointer-to-const and/or pointer-to-volatile (affecting accesses to its instance variables), by appending the keywords `const` or `volatile` to the end of the function definition to which it belongs.

I also know that `this` is sometimes (incorrectly) described as being a const pointer, perhaps as a way of saying "you can't make an assignment to `this`". As an rvalue, it is inherently unassignable, and so there is no need for the concept of a `const` rvalue.

I also know that in C++11, there are cases where being an rvalue or an lvalue can affect call resolution, but I've tried to work through the possibilities, and I'm not sure whether there's a case where it would actually matter to call resolution that `this` is an rvalue pointer rather than a `const` lvalue pointer.

Is there a case where this distinction makes a real difference, from a programmer's perspective, such as a context where an rvalue pointer can be used that a `const` lvalue pointer cannot be used, where a `const` lvalue pointer can be used that an rvalue pointer cannot, or where the difference affects call resolution?

Answer (score 6):

An obvious consequence of `this` being an prvalue is that `&this` is illegal. So, built-in unary operator `&` makes an example of "where a const lvalue pointer can be used that an rvalue pointer cannot". For the very same fundamental reason direct binding of references to `this` is not possible.

Also, prvalue-ness of `this` means that `this` itself cannot be `const` or `volatile`, since scalar rvalues cannot have cv-qualified types.

It is probably hard to build non-esoteric real-life code examples based on these distinctions.

Comment: Another consequence is that capturing `this` in lambda is a special language case (as you can only capture lvalues usually)

Comment: Am I right in saying that, because `&this` is illegal, we also can't pass `this` to a function that takes an rvalue reference? Would that be sufficient to prove that call resolution of a call that passes `this` cannot be affected by its rvalue status? Or might something like [blocking the passing of rvalues as arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307526/c0x-const-rvalue-reference-as-function-parameter) still apply to `this`?

Comment: a real-world legitimate (?) use case of taking the address of `this`: I want to use memcpy() to copy the pointer of the current object to a buffer in order to use it as a unique identifier for logging purposes. E.g.:
`std::vector<uint8_t> log(128); memcpy(log.data(), &this, sizeof(this)); // log relevant data ...`
But that's not allowed, so I have to recur to using a temporary intermediate value instead.