# Why isn't const T && (rvalue reference) an error

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, move-semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do rvalue references to const have any use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938875/do-rvalue-references-to-const-have-any-use)

A common mistake I make is using `const T &&` where it should have been `T &&`.

As far as I can tell, const T && (or, a const rvalue reference) doesn't even make sense. Why isn't it a compile error? I find it frustrating that my move constructors/assigners are being silently ignored when I accidentally use const T &&.

Comment: Yes, it's an exact duplicate of that question. Thanks.