# Move constructor signature

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

From [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible) reference, it allows a `const` rvalue as a move constructor

```
Type::Type( const Type&& other );
```

How can a movable object be `const`? Even if this was technically allowed, is there a case where such declaration would be useful?

Comment: Simple answer: No, there is not, as it defeats the whole purpose of move-semantics. Also note that `&&` doesn't necessarily say "movable". It just says "rvalue reference". And *MoveConstructible* falls back on copying if there is no move ctor, so you could say the `T const&&` move ctor might just copy, but eh.

Comment: Well, `Type` may declare a `mutable` variable and `mutable` variables *can* be modified by `const` move constructors. So a `const` move constructor could just do a shallow copy of the object (while a copy constructor might do a deep copy) and set a `mutable` boolean flag called `dead` or something like that to `true` on the moved object. Then functions of `Type` (most importantly the destructor) would check that flag. Is this nonsense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can a movable object be `const`?

It can't, but that's not what the language says. The language says that a constructor with that signature is a "move constructor" but that doesn't mean the argument gets moved from, it just means the constructor meets the requirements of a "move constructor".  A move constructor is not required to move anything, and if the argument is `const` it can't.

> is there a case where such declaration would be useful?

Yes, but not very often. It can be useful if you want to prevent another constructor being selected by overload resolution when a const temporary is passed as the argument.

```
struct Type
{
  template<typename T>
    Type(T&&);  // accepts anything

  Type(const Type&) = default;    
  Type(Type&&) = default;
};

typedef const Type CType;

CType func();

Type t( func() );   // calls Type(T&&)
```

In this code the temporary returned from `func()` will not match the copy or move constructors' parameters exactly, so will call the template constructor that accepts any type.  To prevent this you could provide a different overload taking a const rvalue, and either delegate to the copy constructor:

```
Type(const Type&& t) : Type(t) { }
```

Or if you want to prevent the code compiling, define it as deleted:

```
Type(const Type&& t) = delete;
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940642/981959 for examples from the standard that use a const rvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

Some background on this feature's intent.

[Rvalue references - From Bjarne Stroustrup's Blog](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#think)

[A Proposal to Add Move Semantics Support to the C++ Language](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm)

An interesting question. I read, somewhere, an explanation of this question by Stroustrup, but can't seem to find it back. Hope the above helps in its stead.