# c++ postfix / prefix operator overload as non-member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, postfix-operator, prefix-operator, non-member-functions

I am writing my own array class as an exercise. Since, I read non-member functions are actually better in some ways than member functions. 
([Scott Meyers](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197))

I am trying to write as many operator overloads as non-member functions as possible. 
The operator overloads + , - all work out fine as non-member functions.

```
my_array operator+(const my_array & left, const my_array & right);
my_array operator-(const my_array & operand);
my_array & operator++();  // prefix
my_array   operator++(int); //postfix, compiler puts a 0
```

However, the prefix/postfix operators as non-member functions give issues (they work fine if I use scope resolution and make them member functions)

I understand that not every operator overload can be member functions. But , I am having trouble as to why these two cannot be non-member functions. The error I get is:

```
: 'my_array& operator++()' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
```

Which basically can be solved if I make them member functions and allow a *this array obj to be passed along in the following format.

```
(*this).operator++();
```

But the whole thing is, I do not want to make them member functions in first place!
So, is it that the pre/post fix operators cannot/should not be implemented as non-member function?

The reasoning I came up with is that, since postfix/prefix is unary operator
they only have one argument (usually a *this).
So, if I want the compiler to provide the *this pointer implicitly and call the overloads, they must be implemented as a member-function.

Is My reasoning correct? If not how do I implement this as a non-member function?
Thanks for providing me with some insight.

Comment: What do your ++ operators do? Call ++ on each element?

Comment: <br>yap, this is just to exercise writing code.<br/>       <pre>     my_array& operator++( my_array & operand) //prefix
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < operand.get_number_of_elements(); ++i)
        {
            ++(operand[i]);
        }
    
        return operand;
    }
    
    my_array  operator++(my_array &operand, int) //postfix
    {
        my_array result(operand);
        ++(operand);
        return result;
       }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstood, but if you're struggling with proper declaration of both operators, you can still do this with free operators like members. You do, however, need to pass the *object* as the first parameter by-reference. You're correct that as member functions they get their object for free via *this*. As a free function, you need to push it yourself.

```
#include <iostream>

struct my_array
{
    // your members here.
};

my_array& operator ++(my_array& obj)
{
    // access to members is through obj.member
    std::cout << "++obj called." << std::endl;
    return obj;
}

my_array operator ++(my_array& obj, int)
{
    my_array prev = obj;

    // modify obj, but return the previous state.        
    std::cout << "obj++ called." << std::endl;

    return prev;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    my_array obj;
    ++obj;
    obj++;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
++obj called.
obj++ called.
```

Comment: that does it.. I was having trouble with how the postfix signature would work in this case. `my_array& operator ++(my_array& obj, int)` answers my question. Some of my reasonings were wrong

Comment: @thassan Actually, the postfix one given in the answer is not the usual one. It should return by value, because it must return the value before the increment.

Comment: @Angew I concur.  It was the param list he was after, but I will update the answer accordingly. Thanks for the eagle-eye.

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually, I spotted it from the review queue, as somebody edited that in, but they changed it to `const my_array`, which I had to reject as invalid. We don't want to return by const value now that move semantics exist.

Comment: @Angew No kidding. I was in the review queue? Ah. someone's *edit* was in the queue. Much appreciated that you brought it here. I've no problem fixing something that isn't correct, to be sure. (still too early here, not enough caffeine yet =P).

Comment: @Angew, "We don't want to return by const value now that move semantics exist" Really? Surely the return value of a postfix operator is a temporary that you do not want to accidentally mutate.

Comment: @AdamBurry But you most definitely want to be able to move from it. And even if you mutate it in antoher way, so what?

Comment: @Angew, ah, now I see the complaint. You should be able to move from a const object. Can you not? I thought const meant thread-safe, not bitwise immutable.

Comment: @AdamBurry It means you cannot modify it. The move ctor/move assignment op would have to take `const my_array&&` as a parameter, and there's not much you can do through a const reference. You certainly can't assign to data members (such as stealing a pointer and setting it to `nullptr`).

Comment: @Angew Thanks for the edit, btw. damn spell-check on my Mac gets a little intrusive when I'm writing code on SO =P.

Comment: @Angew, see: http://herbsutter.com/2013/01/01/video-you-dont-know-const-and-mutable/ and the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100660/xxconst-x-const-move-constructor

Comment: @AdamBurry I've seen Sutter's talk. But the language has its rules - you cannot modify an object through a `const` glvalue, except for the `mutable` members of an object of class type.

Comment: This point discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138780/move-semantics-returning-const-values