# C++11 rvalue reference questions

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue-reference

I am trying to understand new features of C++11, and I have two questions regarding rvalue references.

1. I have not seen examples when functions return rvalue references (except `std::move`). Are there cases when it makes sense to do so? E. g., `int&& foo(...)`.
2. Are there cases when it makes sense to have rvalue references to const, either when declaring local variables or as function arguments? E. g., `foo(int const&& i)`.

Comment: `1)` Move is the main example. `2)` duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938875/do-rvalue-references-to-const-have-any-use <- the dup

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should std::move be used on a function return value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856344/when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value)

Comment: Actually, both questions are duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) I have not seen examples when functions return rvalue references (except `std::move`). Are there cases when it makes sense to do so?

Apart from library functions that are not doing much more than casting their argument to an rvalue reference (such as `std::move` and, when appropriate, `std::forward`) and returning that argument, I don't believe you will meet that very often.

> 2) Are there cases when it makes sense to have rvalue references to `const`?

Not many. Almost none, actually. Rvalue references are used when you want to bind to an object you eventually want to *move* from, and since you cannot move from a `const` object (because moving alters the state of the object you move from, and `const` promises the opposite), it makes little sense to have an rvalue reference to `const`. Also notice, that *lvalue* references to `const` can bind to rvalues as well. There are [a few use cases for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938875/do-rvalue-references-to-const-have-any-use) though.