# Why doesn't C++ have a const universal reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, universal-reference

Scott Meyers [says](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (for parameters to function templates):

> Universal references can only occur in the form "`T&&`"!  Even the
>   simple addition of a `const` qualifier is enough to disable the
>   interpretation of "`&&`" as a universal reference.

Why doesn't C++ have a `const` universal reference? Any technical reason?

Comment: Because the way you use a const rhand reference would be identical to the way you use a const lhand reference in most cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What would a const universal reference be? It would be a reference that can not be modified. And moving from an rvalue-reference is a modification. Therefore, if there is such a thing as a const universal reference, it is simply `const T&`.

Comment: If it is useless, why compiler doesn't forbid `const T&&`? Shouldn't it be forbidden?

Comment: @ccsadegh It's not useless, you might need it in some rare and complicated cases of overload resolution to remove ambiguity. It's just not useful for forming a "const universal reference".

Comment: @Sadeq, checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938875/do-rvalue-references-to-const-have-any-use