# What is use of the ref-qualifier `const &&`?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I've been digging around ref-qualifiers a bit, following on a previous question.

Given the code sample below;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct A {
  std::string abc = "abc";
  std::string& get() & {
    std::cout << "get() &" << std::endl;
    return abc;
  }
  std::string get() && {
    std::cout << "get() &&" << std::endl;
    return std::move(abc);
  }
  std::string const& get() const & {
    std::cout << "get() const &" << std::endl;
    return abc;
  }
  std::string get() const && {
    std::cout << "get() const &&" << std::endl;
    return abc;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a1;
  a1.get();
  const A a2{};
  a2.get();
  A().get();
  const A a3{};
  std::move(a3).get();
}
```

And the output is as you would expect:

> get() & 
>   get() const & 
>   get() && 
>   get() const &&

This compiles and runs with clang and gcc 4.9.1 (not 4.9.0 though). Live [sample here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f167ea69247f0794).

In general code (the sample is there to see how the code compiles and runs).

- What would the purpose of the `const &&` ref-qualifier on a method be?

The method is unable to modify the contents on the object (it is `const`), an attempt to `return std::move(abc);` from the `const &&` method doesn't actually move the `std::string` at all. Presumably you would want to be able modify the object, since it's an r-value and won't be around for long. If the `const &&` qualified method were to be removed, the code `std::move(a3).method()` would bind to  the `const &` qualified method, which would make sense.

- What, if any, would the implied semantic difference be between a method qualified as `const &` and one qualified as `const &&`? I.e. how would the implementation vary or why would you want both?
- Would the `std::string` truely be able to be "moved" out of the temporary object?
- What would a "canonical" signature look like for `std::string get() const &&` in this case?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**On the usefulness of `const&&`... (in general)**

The usefulness of the `const&&` qualifier on the member method is minimal at best. The object cannot be modified in the same manner as a `&&` method would allow it to be modified; it is `const` after all (as noted, `mutable` does change this). So we will not be able to rip out its guts, since the temporary is expiring anyway, as we would in something akin to a normal `move`.

In many ways the usefulness of the `const&&` may be best evaluated in the context of how useful an object of type `const T&&` is to begin with. **How useful is a `const T&&` function argument**? As pointed out in another answer (to this question) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24825006/3747990), they are very useful in declaring functions deleted, e.g. in this case

```
template <class T> void ref (const T&&) = delete;
```

to explicitly disallow objects of prvalue and xvalue value category types from being used with the functions, and `const T&&` does [bind to all prvalue and xvalue objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24943093/3747990).

> What is the usefulness of `const&&` method qualifier?

It is interesting to note that in the proposal [C++ library extensions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4082.pdf), `optional`, § 5.3, includes overloads, e.g.

```
constexpr T value() const &&;
```

that are qualified as `const&&` and are specified to perform the same action as the `&&` alternative.

The reason I can infer for this case; is that this is for completeness and correctness. If the `value()` method is called on an rvalue, then it performs the same action independent of it being `const` or not. The `const` will need to be dealt with by the contained object being moved or the client code using it. If there is some `mutable` state with the object being contained, then that state can legitimately be changed.

There may well still be some merit in this; in no particular order...

- To declare it **`= delete`** to prohibit the method's use on prvalues and xvalues.
- If the type has **mutable state** and the qualifier makes sense (possibly in addition to the other qualifiers) in the target environment, consider it.
- If you are implementing a generic container type, then for **completeness and correctness**, consider adding it and performing the same action as the `&&` method. Advice here is sort from the standard library (and its extensions).

> What would a "canonical" signature look like for a `const&&` qualified method?

Since the method will be performing the same action as the `&&` method, I would advocate that the signature matches the `&&` signature.

Comment: "If you are implementing a generic container type, then for completeness and correctness, consider adding it and performing the same action as the && method." — You can't, because the container and its contents are to be treated as `const`. The `const &` qualified method will be called instead for `const` rvalue object access.

Comment: @Potatoswatter. That it how it is specified in the C++ Library Extensions for `optional` et. al. The `&&` and `const&&` methods effect the same thing (n4082, section 5.3.5 para 11, 20 etc.). It is worth noting that GCC has an issue selecting the correct method given a const rvalue, but clang does not. I think the point here is that in general, there is no use, but there are a few corner cases lying around that may just require it (and then consider carefully why you need it).

Answer (score 12):

We can find a similar exploration of this issue in the article [What are const rvalue references good for?](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/07/24/const-rvalue-references/) and the one use that stood out is this example form the standard library:

```
template <class T> void ref (const T&&) = delete;
template <class T> void cref (const T&&) = delete;
```

which disables `ref` and `cref` for rvalues altogether. We can find these declarations in the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `20.8` *Function objects* paragraph *2*.

Scott Meyers alludes to this use in [Universal References in C++11](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers):

> Even the simple addition of a const qualifier is enough to disable the
>   interpretation of “&&” as a universal reference:

Comment: I think I agree with the article, in general, especially with the ref-qualified methods, there is little use other than to prohibit it from being used.

Comment: Note that there are multiple relevant questions on SO that predate that article.  For example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4938875/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt there are a few of them, I did not go beyond my first search hit since it answered the question very nicely and it actually neatly explored the issue in a very similar way. This question though is by far the best quality.

Comment: Ref qualifiers never indicate universal references anyway. I don't see how this answer relates to the question.

Comment: Your answer is not very clear. Is `const T&&` really going to take only r-values? Why not implement only `template <class T> void ref (const T&)`? In this case, trying to pass r-values will fail. If what you wrote is true, then it is stupid use of `const T&&`

Comment: @BЈовић, I asked something similar previously http://stackoverflow.com/q/24943093/3747990

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have a type with a `mutable` state.  Then `const&&` will both allow us to mutate that state, and indicate that such mutation is safe.

```
struct bar;

struct foo {
  mutable std::vector<char> state;
  operator bar() const&;
  operator bar() const&&;
};
```

`const` is not absolute.

Barring mutable state, it is not safe to cast away `const` in a `const&&` method in order to extract state, because extracting state in this way from an actual `const` object is undefined behavior.

Comment: `mutable` brings something very interesting to the table, because it also says something about thread safety as well in C++11.

Comment: @niall only if in `std` containers.  Or types provided by `std`.

Comment: That's a good point. I agree, technically yes. From a personal point of view though, I do generally expect types to be usable with and by the standard library. Given the current levels of conformance found in general implementations, I think we all could or should - it would be counter-intuitive if that was not the case. I think the standard library provides a reasonably good model for us to follow. I do also understand thought that this won't always be applicable - but I think these cases are or should be limited (I know of some).

Answer (score 2):

I see two main uses for ref-qualifying a method. One is like you show in your `get() &&` method, where you use it to select a potentially more efficient implementation that is only available when you know the object will no longer be used. But the other is a safety hint to prevent calling certain methods on temporary objects.

You can use notation like `get() const && = delete` in such cases, although realistically I would save this approach for modifying methods, especially those that are potentially costly. It doesn't make much sense to mutate and then discard an object without retrieving something, and doubly so if it's expensive to perform the mutation. This construct gives the compiler a way to flag and prevent such usage.

Comment: The `=delete` gives you a lot of control over how the object can not be used, I think this would be `const&&` general use (if at all).