# constructor with nested variadic template arguments of different type arithmetics

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, variadic-templates, sfinae

follow up to [initialize double nested std::array from variadic template array reference constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65310179/initialize-double-nested-stdarray-from-variadic-template-array-reference-const)

### Problem

I have a `Matrix` class that does can do some math. But this is purely about initialization...

`Matrix`

```cpp
// helper functions
template <std::size_t N, typename T, std::size_t... Is>
std::array<T, N> to_array_impl(const T (&arr)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return std::array<T, N>{arr[Is]...};
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
std::array<T, N> to_array(const T (&arr)[N]) {
  return to_array_impl(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

// Matrix
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t M, typename T>
class Matrix{
  public:

    template <typename... TArgs,
      std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(TArgs) == N &&
             (std::is_same_v<T, std::remove_reference_t<TArgs>> &&...), int> = 0>
    Matrix(TArgs const(&&... rows)[M]) : data_{to_array(rows)...} {}

    // ...

    private:
      std::array<Vector<M,T>, N> data; // <- custom Vector class but uses an std::array for its data
};
```

One can initialize it as follows (which works just fine)

```
Matrix<2, 2, int> m{ {3,4}, {5,6} };
```

But i would like to allow the variadic template constructor to accept different types inside the initializer list. In that case, it should apply narrowing.
For example:

```
Matrix<2, 2, int> m{ {3,4}, {5,6.5F} }; // does not compile
// should be [ [3,4], [5,6] ]
```

**I'm fully aware that this can't work here** because the constructor only accepts the same type that the `Matrix` was defined with by using `std::is_same`. I changed the constructor to use `std::is_arithmetic` instead (because the class should only accept arithmetic types or references of such. it also contains a static asserts that checks the template parameter `T` at initialization, but that's not really important here)

New constructor

```cpp
template <typename... TArgs,
   std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(TArgs) == N &&
          (std::is_arithmetic_v<T, std::remove_reference_t<TArgs>> &&...), int> = 0> // <--- is_arithmetic
Matrix(TArgs const(&&... rows)[M]) : data_{to_array(rows)...} {}
```

clang error

```
<source>:55:3: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'TArgs'  ('int' vs. 'float')
Matrix(TArgs const(&... rows)[M]) : data{to_array(rows)...} {}
```

As far as i understand, the deduction cannot be made for the values inside an initializer list, inside an initializer list.

Because this is a double nesting, i have this problem. If the variadic template constructor is NOT nested, this works fine. It just requires a static_cast or a change to the compiler options to silence the compiler about implicit narrowing. For example, i have a `Vector` that works just as i want with this.

`Vector`

```cpp
template <typename... TArgs,
   std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(TArgs) == N &&
          (std::is_arithmetic_v<T, std::remove_reference_t<TArgs>> &&...), int> = 0>
Vector(TArgs &&... args)[M]) : data_{std::forward<TArgs>(args)...} {}
//                                   ^^ use static_cast here or general compiler option
```

example code

```cpp
Vector<3,int> v{3, 4, 5.5F}; // compiles
// will be [3, 4, 5]
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/McdGbb)

### Question

Is it possible tp make the nested variadic template constructor in `Matrix` accept different types for the individual values, so that it applies narrowing if necesary to match the template type `T`?

Comment: *"In that case, it should apply narrowing"* list-initialization tries to _prevent_ narrowing, because that's considered error-prone...

Comment: i see. do you have a link that elaborates?

Comment: Strangely, I cannot quickly find good examples of _why narrowing is bad_. Well, narrowing is surprising, since you loose information without any hint/warning. For example, if I write `Vector<3, int> v{1.2, 1.4, 5.4};` and I mistakenly used type `int` instead of `double`, then I'm a bit surprised that `v[0] != 1.2`.

Comment: Details about _what narrowing is_: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization (section "Narrowing conversions"), http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-narrowing and https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-rules-for-conversions-and-casts

Comment: definitely does make sense, no question. was just wondering if it's possible somehow. i guess my case is mainly "conversion from a floating-point type to an integer type" so it's not possible with list initialization.

Comment: Is there maybe a way though to explicitly use static_cast in the Matrix constructor like i indicated in the Vector constructor?

Comment: Re: references for narrowing conversions. See [dcl.init.aggr] that says a narrowing conversion during aggregate initialization is ill-formed. See [dcl.init.list] that says a narrowing conversion during list-initialization of a class type is ill-formed.

Answer (score 5):

The main issue here is that an initializer list cannot deduce a type when its contents are heterogeneous, so `{1, 2, 3.F}` won't work. A secondary issue is that, even if the type is specified, you will get compiler errors if there is an implicit narrowing conversion (e.g., `double` -> `int`)

We have to somehow turn our heterogeneous initializer list into a homogenous collection.

## Approach #1

Make a little helper function to convert your arguments into an appropriate `std::array<T, M>`:

```
template<class T, class... Ts>
auto make_array(Ts&&... args) -> std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)>
{
    return {static_cast<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args))...};
}
```

It's not so pretty at the callsite:

```
Matrix<2,3,int> m{ make_array<int>(1,2.0,3.F), make_array<int>(4.0,5U,6)};
```

But it's fairly straightforward to write your constructor:

```
template<class... Ts, std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) == N && (std::is_same_v<Ts, std::array<T, M>> && ...), int> = 0>
Matrix(Ts&&... args) : data{std::forward<Ts>(args)...}
{
}
```

#### [Demo 1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yC181vaMaj67cOJd)

## Approach #2

We do **a lot** of work to make it slightly prettier from the callsite

**Here's an idea:**

Allow for each member of the list to be a `variant<T...>` for each possible type in the list, then accept a number of these lists of variants into your matrix for construction.

So basically, convert `{1, 2, 3.0}` into a `std::array<std::variant<int, double>, 3>`

And then take a variadic number of these arrays as arguments to a constructor for your matrix, with appropriate type-constraining on them (each array is the appropriate size, each type in the variant is convertible to `T`).

Inside your constructor, you can use a visitor to perform conversion of each array value to `T`. Since `std::variant` is C++17 and you're stuck with C++14, you can use a [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) (and appropriate visitor).

**Unfortunately** what follows is quite a lot of boilerplate. Probably someone else can find something simpler

I will use a few C++17 features (a fold expression, `std::disjunction`), but these can be implemented in C++14 (I *do* use a technique called simple template expansion that is C++14 compatible, in place of a fold expression).

(Or skip straight to the [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TqbSDesALPKU2TEN))

---

First things first, since a `std::variant` allows the same type to appear in its type list  multiple times (e.g., `std::variant<int, double, int>`), we should prefer to unique-ify this type list to avoid the ambiguities that come with it (this part is not exactly necessary, but I encourage it).

To do so, we are going to need a few helper types for our meta-programming

1. a `typelist` to represent an arbitrary collection of types
2. a `unique_typelist` that will transform a `typelist` into a `typelist` of unique types
3. `variant_from_typelist` to convert a `typelist` into a `std::variant<T...>`

And finally a way to create a `std::array<std::variant<T...>, N>` given some set of arguments of type `T...`.

First I'll show you the types, and then do my best to explain them:

### 1. a `typelist` to represent an arbitrary collection of types:

```
template<class...>
struct typelist{};
```

This is our easiest type to understand. We could use `tuple<T...>`, but this is lighter-weight since we aren't actually carrying around any values.

### 2. a `unique_typelist` that will transfrom a `typelist` into a `typelist` of unique types

This here is the tricky bit that requires its own extra boilerplate:

- a way to detect if a type `Head` appears in a variadic typelist `Tail...`

For that, we'll use `std::disjunction` in conjunction with `std::same_as` to do this detection (note: you may want to remove cvrefs in a fully-functioning impl):

```
template<class Head, class... Tail>
using is_present = std::disjunction<std::is_same<Head, Tail>...>;
```

`is_present` becomes `std::true_type` if `Head` is the same as any type in the variadic `Tail` list.

Then we need a way to incrementally build our unique typelist for each type in a pack

1. If `Head` does appear in our pack, the resulting `typelist` should not include `Head`

   - Recurse only on `Tail...`
2. Else, since `Head` *doesn't* appear in our pack, we want to construct a typelist of `concatenate(typelist<Head>, RecurseOn<Tail...>)`

   - where `RecurseOn<Tail...>` is pseudocode for "create a unique typelist of the members of the tail
   - and `concatenate` is a meta-function for appending one typelist to another

     - e.g., `concatenate(typelist<int>, typelist<double>)` will give `typelist<int, double>`

So to do so, we'll enable the ability to concatenate (and in my impl I need to worry about  an empty `typelist` in the right-hand argument, so there is a specialization for it):

```
template<class... T>
struct concat;

template<class... T, class... U>
struct concat<typelist<T...>, typelist<U...>>
{
    using type = typelist<T..., U...>;
};

template<class... T>
struct concat<typelist<T...>, typelist<>>
{
    using type = typelist<T...>;
};
```

Now, with the aide of [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) we can construct our set of unique types:

```
template<class... T>
struct unique_typelist
{
    using type = typelist<>;
};

template<class Head, class... Tail>
struct unique_typelist<Head, Tail...>
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<is_present<Head, Tail...>::value,
         typename unique_typelist<Tail...>::type, // if condition is true
          typename concat<typelist<Head>, typename unique_typelist<Tail...>::type>::type>;
};
```

It's not easy to wrap your head around all the recursion here, so take your time, and feel free to comment with questions for clarification.

### 3. convert a typelist into a std::variant<T...>

Now that we have a `typelist<Ts...>` where each `T` in `Ts...` is unique, we write some helper classes to convert a `NonUnique...` into a `std::variant<Unique...>` (`NonUnique` and `Unique` are intended to be names for variadic template parameters).

```
template<class...>
struct typelist_to_variant;

template<class... T>
struct typelist_to_variant<typelist<T...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<T...>;
};

template<class...>
struct unique_typelist_to_variant;

template<class... T>
struct unique_typelist_to_variant<unique_typelist<T...>>
{
    using type = typename typelist_to_variant<typename unique_typelist<T...>::type>::type;
};

template<class... T>
struct variant_from_types
{
    using type = typename unique_typelist_to_variant<unique_typelist<T...>>::type;
};

template <class... T>
using variant_from_types_t = typename variant_from_types<T...>::type;
```

This is better read from the bottom-up:
Given some set of possibly-duplicate types `T...`, we:

- convert `T...` into a `typelist<U...>` where each `U` is unique, then
- strip the `typelist` part away from `U...` to be placed into a `std::variant`

### 4. create a std::arraystd::variant<T..., N> given some set of arguments of type T...

Given what I just put you through, this is fairly straightforward:

```
template<class... T>
constexpr auto make_variant_array(T&&... args) -> std::array<variant_from_types_t<T...>, sizeof...(T)>
{
    return {std::forward<T>(args)...};
};
```

We already wrote the `variant_from_types_t` helper to get our `std::variant<U...>` so that all types in `U...` are unique, now it's just a matter of passing along some arguments to construct our array.

### 5. Create a constrained-constructor for `Matrix` that accepts a variadic number of these "arrays of variant" and then initializes its data with a visitor.

To constrain the template, we're interested in enforcing that each array is of size `M`, and that there are `N` such arrays. For that, a small type-trait helper is nice:

```
template<size_t N, class T>
struct is_variant_array : std::false_type{};

template<size_t N, class... T>
struct is_variant_array<N, std::array<std::variant<T...>, N>> : std::true_type{};
```

`is_variant_array` asks the question "Is `T` an array of size `N` where each element is a `std::variant`?"

Let's see it in action in our `Matrix` constructor:

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t M, typename T>
class Matrix{
  public:
    template<class... Ts, std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) == N && (is_variant_array<M, Ts>::value && ...), int> = 0>
    Matrix(Ts&&... args)
{ /*...*/}
```

(I leave it as an exercise to the reader to further constrain these arrays such that each type in their variants is convertible to `T`).

### 6. Use a visitor to convert each variant into `T` to initialize our `data` member:

For this, we'll write a fairly straightforward visitor that attempts to convert everything it gets to some type `T` via `static_cast`:

```
template<class T>
struct cast_visitor
{
    template<class U>
    T operator()(U u) const
    {
        return static_cast<T>(u);
    }
};
```

Then, we'll use it inside our constructor with a little pre-[fold expreesion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) trick I (we?) call simple expansion that involves a discarded-value expression and a comma operator to enforce ordering:

```
cast_visitor<T> visitor;
std::size_t i = 0;
auto add_row = [&, this](auto varray)
{
   for(size_t j = 0; j < M; ++j)    
   {
       data[i][j] = std::visit(visitor, varray[j]);
   }
};
    
using swallow = size_t[];
(void)swallow{(void(add_row(args)), ++i)...};
```

### 7. Finally we are ready to call our constructor!

```
Matrix<2,3,int> m{ make_variant_array(1,2,3), make_variant_array(4,5,6)};
```

It's not pretty, but it gets the job done.

#### [Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TqbSDesALPKU2TEN)

Comment: Wow, great and detailed answer! When i experimented myself with code i didn't show here, it kind of started to have some parts of what you described here in much more detail. I feared that a caller would have to use some method like your `make_variant_array` to convert the individual types...since i want to make it as easy as possible for a caller, i won't implement this. But i can see that parts of your answer can help me with some other pieces of my internal code :)

Comment: @mtosch: Great to hear. Fun to write some deep templating every now and then