# Understanding rule of zero

Tags: c++, c++11, rule-of-zero

I have a base class, and I do not want to make derived class copyable. In order to make everything explicit I implement it in that way:

```
class A {                                                                     
public:    
    A() = default;                                                                   
    virtual ~A() = default;                                                   
    A(const A&)  = delete;                                                    
    A(const A&&) = delete;                                                    
    A& operator=(const A&)  = delete;                                         
    A& operator=(const A&&) = delete;                                         

    virtual void vFun() = 0;                                                  
};                                                                            

class B : public A {                                                          
public:
    B() = default;                                                                       
    virtual ~B() = default;                                                   
    B(const B&)  = delete;                                                    
    B(const B&&) = delete;                                                    
    B& operator=(const B&)  = delete;                                         
    B& operator=(const B&&) = delete;                                         

    virtual void vFun() override {}                                           
};
```

Is this correct way of doing such things? According to my knowledge and what I have read, the answer is yes, but I would like to be sure before I introduce it into production system.

---

### EDIT

Taking things into conclusion:
1) Almost always move operators should not be deleted. That's because "there's an infinity of things that require movability".
2) For abstract base class, it's safer to allow compiler to generate special member function, and move deletion into derived class if such necessity exists.

Comment: The move constructors should take `A &&` rather than `const A &&`.

Comment: You have also deleted the move constructor and move assigner, did you mean to make the class _unmovable_ in addition to being uncopyable? Btw `const T&&` [is probably not what you want](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4938875/3425536).

Comment: You don't want to make derived class copyable, but.. then you delete the *move* operators?

Comment: Right, I removed const and, after wondering for a while, default move constructor makes sense.

Comment: @galvanize Please don't edit your question like that - it invalidates answers.

Comment: 1) Don't completely re-edit the question when answers are posted 2) Without knowing if your class deals with ownership and/or what it is supposed to do it's hard to answer objectively and only observations can be posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, this is completely incorrect.

Firstly, in your quest to make the derived class noncopyable, you have made it non-*movable*, which renders it nearly useless.

Secondly, there's no reason for A to be noncopyable at all. Each derived class can just make itself noncopyable if it wants to. A is already abstract and cannot be sliced so there's no reason to make A noncopyable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why non-movability makes it nearly useless?

Comment: Because there's an infinity of things that require movability? Like containers, algorithms, etc.

Comment: Good point, but you don't always need to use your classes with containers and algorithms, and the class could still be considered useful.

Comment: Question is broad but I'm upvoting this since it makes some good points.

Comment: "Nope, this is completely incorrect". There are cases, where such implementation would work.