# Applications of const&& in range-for?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, constants, rvalue-reference

Are there any cases in which it does make sense to use `const&&` in range-for loops?

```
for (const auto && x : c) // ?
```

Comment: Are there any cases where `const &&` makes sense *anywhere*?

Comment: @immibis I know of [one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)

Comment: I was interested to the particular context of range-for. I saw `const auto &&` used in a range-for in [this code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2015/11/16/recursively-deleting-a-directorywith-long-filename-support/) and was curious about it. Instead of `for (const auto && it : dl)` I'd just have used `for (const auto & ...)`, for _observing_ items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: **no**, there are no uses for `const auto&&` in `range-for loops` (or otherwise)

You would use `rvalue references` if you wish to move objects in an optimized manner. You can't do that (in general) unless you can modify the object moved from. So `const rvalues` (*) are of no practical use (you can't move from them because you can't modify them).

`range-for loops` don't bring anything to the table in this discussion about `const auto&&`.

---

Check for instance this SO post: [Do rvalue references to const have any use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938875/do-rvalue-references-to-const-have-any-use)

The only found use of const rvalue reference is to delete some function overloads. This doesn't apply to `range-for loops`.

---

(*) by the way, `const auto&&` is a const rvalue reference, not a forwarding reference.

Comment: Well, you are guaranteed to prevent elements being modified - but if that is desired, simple const reference would be more straitghtforward.

Comment: @SergeyA the only reason you would use rvalue references is if you wish to effectively move from them.

Comment: Your answer seems to confirm what I thought, i.e. there are no valid uses of `const auto &&` in range-for loops. I'm marking it as answer, unless some new interesting idea shows up in another answer.

Comment: Can you explain, why this isn't a forwarding/universal reference?

Comment: @MikeMB because only `T&&`  where `T` is deduced (or `auto&&`) is an fowarding reference. see https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: Good to know I forgot that const is enough to turn it into a r-value reference.