# Can someone explain the difference in these function return types

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't understand the difference in the following return types and how can some of them even compile?

```
const bool && const Method1(){
    .....
}
```

What is the return of this ? Constant (rval) reference to constant value?

```
const bool const Method1(){
    .....
}
```

Constant boolean constant ( I dont understand this how can there be two constants here if i'm returning a value)

```
const bool & const Method1(){
    .....
}
```

Also no idea, constant reference to constant value?

Which one is best to use for read only return value ?

Comment: `const bool& const` won't even compile, unlike `const bool* const`.

Comment: compiles using ms-vc++ 15

Comment: g++ says: _error: ‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘const bool&’_

Comment: I would encourage you to start by asking yourself a few basic things you know about references, such as 'can a reference be reassigned?'

Comment: Here's a minimal set of options for Visual C++ (from memory): `/nologo /EHsc /GR /W4 /FI"iso646.h"`. Try to compile with these options.

Answer (score 0):

1. `const bool const Method1();`
   does not compile.
2. `const bool&& Method1();`
   it compiles. About its utility [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938875/do-rvalue-references-to-const-have-any-use) some references.
3. `const bool & const Method1();` does not compile.

**References**: [here](https://ideone.com/OJcsx6), and [here](https://ideone.com/nYd7W5).

---

### Update

With *Visual Studio* it gives me

```
main.cpp(5): warning C4114: same type qualifier used more than once
main.cpp(6): warning C4227: anachronism used: qualifiers on reference are ignored
```

which simply says Visual Studio ignores that qualifiers (form *(1)*, *(3)*).

Comment: They all compile under ms-vc++ 2015

Comment: Also I never asked for  const bool const&

Comment: @johns193 *"Also I never asked for const bool const&"* Ok, there is no point in that form