# Why does the const rvalue qualified std::optional::value() return a const rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++17, rvalue-reference, stdoptional

`std::optional::value()` has the following two overloads

```
constexpr T& value() &;
constexpr const T & value() const &; 
constexpr T&& value() &&;
constexpr const T&& value() const &&;
```

What is the point of returning a const rvalue reference?

The only reason I can think of is to enable the compiler to help catch undefined behavior in (really really weird) cases like the following

```
auto r = std::cref(const_cast<const std::optional<int>&&>(
    std::optional<int>{}).value());
```

Where if the `std::optional::value()` had returned a `const T&` then the above code would compile and would lead to undefined behavior when the `r` `reference_wrapper` was used later.

Is there any other corner case in mind with the above returning a `const T&&`?

Comment: Can't take the credit for other peoples' knowledge, but here's a link: http://www.nirfriedman.com/2016/01/18/writing-good-cpp-by-default-in-the-stl/ In section "Safe Iteration Optional" there is some useful info about where `T&& value()` is used.

Comment: It would be unsafe to return a non-const reference to a const object ... and also unsafe to return an lvalue reference to what might be a temporary object... ergo, it returns a const rvalue reference

Comment: What would be the alternative you're suggesting? A non-`const` rvalue reference? A `const` lvalue reference?

Comment: I'm wondering why they needed to add that overload at all instead of just one `const T&` overload.  And if they needed to why not just return a `const T&` in that case?  Is there some actual use case for that overload?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4938875/2069064)? Ultimately, this question is just: what is the point of `T const&&`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.  You have a `const optional<T>` in struct.  You return an rvalue instance and access the optional member.

Because of how you constructed it, you can guarantee the optional is engaged in this case.  So you call `value()`.  The type `T` contains `mutable` state that can be efficiently be reused/stolen.  The `T const&&` overload gives the consuming function permission to steal that state.

```
struct mutable_type {
  mutable std::vector<char> cache;
};
struct test_type {
  const std::optional<mutable_type> bob;
};
test_type factory( int x ) {
  if (x==0) return {};
  return {mutable_type({{1,2,x}})};
}

auto moved_into = factory(3).bob.value().cache;
```

This, I believe, moves the `vector` within `bob`, which is a `const` rvalue in this context.  It relies on `value()` returning a `const&&` in a `const&&` context.

Comment: How can a `const T&&` overload give permission to a function to steal its state?  I don't think I follow...

Comment: @curious the state is mutable in this case, so const blocks nothing.  `&&` means the object is an rvalue or being cast to an rvalue, so the caller promises not to mind if you steal some state.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Curious toy example added.

Comment: Won't this example work even if the `value()` method had returned a `const&`?

Comment: @Curious No, you should not move from a `const&`, even mutable data.  In that case, we'd copy the data.  A `const&` is a const lvalue, not a const rvalue.  Lvalues may be used later; silently stealing from them is rude. rvalues mean "sure, steal my stuff if you need it".  In the case of my code above, it should evaluate to a copy for `const&` and a move for `const&&`.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I understand, fetching the `mutable` value from the `const&&` yields a `&&` and not a `const&&`.  Clever!

Comment: Is the `return {};` valid? `test_type`'s default constructor will be deleted, but the `{}` will value-initialize it, which checks the constraints of default initialization.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What makes `test_type`'s default constructor be deleted?  The `const` member?

Comment: @Yakk um, I looked up and it appears that `{}` will prefer aggregate initialization over value initialization. So it seems fine.