# How can I create and add a unique_ptr to a vector in a method?

Tags: c++, clang++

I am trying to use polymorphism to represent a tree of sorts (terminal and non-terminal nodes for a parser). One of the classes `Node` holds a vector of smart pointers to subclasses of `Base`. I'd like to add more nodes to this vector with a method that accepts just a `Node` reference without having to create the smart pointer outside of the class (or is this terrible practice?).

The `void addNode(const std::unique_ptr<Node> &&node)` overload works, but I'd like to use the
`void addNode(const Node &&node)` overload.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to create and move this smart pointer into the vector without breaking the copy elision rule or calling the copy constructor of Node and I'm not exactly sure why. It looks like `make_unique` is always invoking the copy-constructor of Node. I've tried using these statements:

```cpp
nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>(node));
```

Gives a compiler error `call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor`. This makes sense, thought I just had to `std::move` it.

---

```cpp
nodes.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<Node>(node)));
```

Same error as above, also: `moving a temporary object prevents copy elision`.

---

```cpp
nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(node)));
```

Just gives the `call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor`.

---

```cpp
nodes.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(node))));
```

Even tried this, which gives both errors as well.

Here is my repro:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Base {};
class Node;
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > Nodes;

class Node : public Base {
  Nodes nodes;

public:
  Node() {};
  void addNode(const Node &&node) {
    nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>(node));
    //nodes.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<Node>(node)));
    //nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(node)));
    //nodes.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(node))));
  }

  void addNode(std::unique_ptr<Node> &&node) {
    nodes.push_back(std::move(node));
  }
};

int main()
{
  Node rootNode;
  rootNode.addNode(Node());
  rootNode.addNode(std::make_unique<Node>());
  return 0;
}
```

I am compiling on MacOS with Clang++ and C++20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you want to move const object?

It should be:

```
void addNode(Node &&node) {
    nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(node)));
}
```

by move, you modify moved instance, so it should be modifable.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zdh5eEaez)

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to `void addNode(const Node &&node)` taking a const rvalue reference, which are a big oddity of extremely dubious utility (there are a few corner cases they might make sense, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938875/do-rvalue-references-to-const-have-any-use) for more).

Given that you can't move from a `const Node&&` (it is constant, after all), the implicitly generated move constructor (`Node(Node&&)`) fails to match.

Due to an old quirk inherited from C++03 `const T&` can bind to rvalues, so a `const T&&` can decay to `const T&`.This causes the compiler to attempt to invoke `Node(const Node&)`, aka the copy constructor, which is deleted due to the fact that `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` is not moveable, which is also due to `std::unique_ptr<T>` not being moveable.