# (C++) Can const members still be moved/forwarded from an rvalue?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

Say I have a class `My<X>` with a member `X x` that it won't modify without being moved/destroyed. I believe that `x` should be a `const X`, because the variable shouldn't be mutable throughout the lifespan of `My<X>`, no matter how its value was given or how it will be gotten. That said, I want the value and its type to be preserved through `My`, as if perfectly forwarded instead.

(I've penciled in pass-through conversion operators just to show the signatures explicitly. In practice, there may be no operators at all, but methods/functions will still use `x` as if by conversion with these CV/references.)

```
template<class X> struct My {
    const X x;
    /* 1. */ operator X && (void) && noexcept;
        //{ return std::forward<X>(std::move(*this).x); }
    /* 2. */ operator const X && (void) && noexcept;
        //{ return std::forward<const X>(std::move(*this).x); }
    /* 3. */ operator X const& (void) const& noexcept
          { return x; }
};
```

I included #2 but I think I can rule it out. I've looked up `const X &&` enough to remember that [it has few interpretations and few use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60587511). The `const` here was added, I only want to preserve `const` if it already was.

As for #1, the call to `std::forward<X>` should be a `static_cast<X &&>`, so I believe the type is right. Can I use perfect forwarding this way, or will I have copies or dangling references or something?

(I recently did a lot of tests on CV-qualifications and references, sanity checks really, and discovered some weird behaviors that left me a lot less sure of myself. One is that adding `const` to an lvalue reference has no effect. In fact, it produces a warning, unlike with `std::add_const_t`. That may actually be a factor here.)

Can a moving struct perfectly forward a member currently marked `const`? Is there a reason I shouldn't?

Comment: Moving-construct a const object actually does copy (unless special (rare) constructor taking `const Object&&`).

Comment: So the `static_cast<X &&>(x)` has to make an rvalue and only can by copying, right? What if `X` is already an rvalue, does that fall under `const Object &&`? That's more what I meant. The way I wrote `const X` might not be right for that purpose though.

Comment: Your `std::forward` should simply be `std::move`. So `/*2*/` might simply be `return std::move(x);`. Problem with `/*1*/` is the `const` which should be dropped to compile (`const_cast`), but doing so would lead to UB if returned object is modified.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the reason for making `x` `const` in the first place - and what's the reason for `(void)` in your operators?

Comment: If you don't want `x` to be modified, make it a private member  and don't provide any mutating member functions (and no friends :-).

Comment: @Jarod42 Are you sure, `std::move(const X &&)` is okay? Bear in mind that the `X` in `X &&` may very well be some `Y const&`.

@TedLyngmo Internally, it's meant to be const, period. Think of any reason you would ever need const; that. Now imagine you want to do that on your way to perfect-forwarding the value into a function like `std::forward_as_tuple`. You can compose algorithms/functors that are const with respect to that one variable but can have other mutable state. More in a sec.

Comment: @BoP That sort of relies on you never calling const into question. It wouldn't be a compiler error if a regular method tried to modify it - you're just supposed to know that this class should only have const methods, or that it should avoid modifying certain members from non-const methods... and what, that goes in the comments? "Please don't touch"? In any case, that's a design philosophy, not a response to the technical question I asked. Sorry.

Comment: `std::move(temporary())` is useless `temporary()` is similar. with `const Y y;` `std::move(y)` returns a `const Y&&` (it is ok, even if `const Object&&` is rarely useful).

Comment: `const` member leads to several "issues"/constraint (as not assignable, copy instead of move, ...). Similarly, reference member have some constraint too. Simpler is generally to avoid them.

Comment: @John - *"Please don't touch"?* I thought **you** were writing this class and didn't want any users modifiying the value. If you let others modify the class, about the first thing that happens would be for them to remove the `const` so that their new `set_x()` compiles.

Comment: _"Think of any reason you would ever need const"_ - Well, `const` member _variables_ are i.m.o. rarely needed or useful. As mentioned above, just make them `private` and don't change them _unless_ it's for moving. If you have a `const std::vector<std::string>` member for example, it will be copied instead of moved which can be pretty expensive. It's just not very practical.

Comment: @BoP I'm writing the class, and yes, I don't want users modifying the variable, not from this class anyway. And you're right, a user can circumvent or remove strong typing, assertions, etc. just to pass compilation artificially. In that case the best solution is to remove the user.

Comment: _" In that case the best solution is to remove the user"_ -  Best solution I've heard Today! :-)