# constant rvalue reference (type const &&) as a parameter

Tags: c++

Why does C++ allow constant rvalue references ? I just noticed that this will be actually used by

```
std::pair<T1, T2>::pair::pair( const pair<U1, U2> &&p )
```

Comment: It allows you to move const-qualified variables. Usually you won't be able to implement move semantics of a const object, but there may be some scenarios where the resources are held inside a mutable member variable. Why make this inconsistent with normal references, if there may be a use case for this, even if it's a rare one?

Comment: does this post answer the question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938875/do-rvalue-references-to-const-have-any-use