# C++: Pass string literal or variable to function

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing, rvalue-reference, lvalue

I have a function `f` that takes a string as input. I usually want to provide a string literal, e.g., `f("hello")`. However, I want to implement another function `g` that builds upon `f`:

```
std::string f(const std::string&& x) {
  return x + " world";
}

std::string g(const std::string&& x) {
  std::string res = f(x);  // problem: rvalue reference to std::string cannot bind to lvalue of type std::string
  res += "!";
  return res;
}

int main() {
  std::string res_a = f("hello");
  std::string res_b = g("world");
  return 0;
}
```

How can I achieve this in C++11/14 in a way that I can use `f` with string literals as well as variables?

Comment: change `&&` to `&` for `f`

Comment: Remove `const`. Rvalue reference variable `x` is lvalue. Use `std::move(x)`.

Comment: @JaMiT I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: @AmirulAkmal Changing `&&` to `&` for `f` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way to take a read-only parameter is by `const` *lvalue* reference.

```cpp
std::string f(const std::string& x)
```

This rule of thumb applies to many types, not just `std::string`. The primary exceptions are types that are not bigger than a pointer (e.g. a `char`).

It's rather unusual for a function to have a `const` rvalue reference. As you discovered, that adds difficulty when trying to pass a variable as the argument. A non-`const` rvalue reference has value, but a `const` rvalue reference is inferior to a `const` lvaue reference in most cases. See also [Do rvalue references to const have any use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938875/do-rvalue-references-to-const-have-any-use)

Answer (score 2):

A generic way of solving the problem of a function taking both l-value and r-value references is to use templated functions like so-

```
template <typename T>
T f(T&& val) {
}

template <typename T>
T g(T&& val) {
  T some_val = f(std::forward<T>(val));
}
```

`std::foward<T>(val)` forwards an l-value as an l-value and an r-value as an r-value, just as its name implies.

By templating the function, you ensure that this logic works for any type and not just strings.

Comment: Be careful with the return type. For an lvalue argument it will a reference type.